# Inconsistencies with documentation in response from Apple's verifyReceipt endpoint

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, apple-push-notifications, receipt-validation

I'm in the process of setting up receipt validation for Apple's auto-renewable subscriptions on our server and noticed some inconsistencies with the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt). When verifying a sandbox receipt with the sandbox verifyReceipt endpoint, the response looks as follows:

```
{  
  "auto_renew_status": 1,  
  "status": 0,  
  "auto_renew_product_id": "app.xxx",  
  "receipt": {  
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2020-03-18 01:11:45 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "quantity": "1",  
    "unique_vendor_identifier": "6D2xxx194",  
    "bvrs": "2",  
    "expires_date_formatted": "2020-03-20 12:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",  
    "purchase_date_ms": "1584703627636",  
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2020-03-20 05:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "is_trial_period": "false",  
    "item_id": "15xxx27",  
    "unique_identifier": "cd5xxx424",  
    "original_transaction_id": "100xxx735",  
    "subscription_group_identifier": "20xxx02",  
    "transaction_id": "100xxx439",  
    "web_order_line_item_id": "100xxx419",  
    "version_external_identifier": "0",  
    "purchase_date": "2020-03-20 11:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
    "product_id": "app.xxx",  
    "expires_date": "1584707227636",  
    "original_purchase_date": "2020-03-18 08:11:45 Etc/GMT",  
    "purchase_date_pst": "2020-03-20 04:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "bid": "app.xxx",  
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1584519105000"  
  },  
  "latest_receipt_info": {  
    "original_purchase_date_pst": "2020-03-18 01:11:45 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "quantity": "1",  
    "unique_vendor_identifier": "6D2xxx194",  
    "bvrs": "2",  
    "expires_date_formatted": "2020-03-20 12:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",  
    "purchase_date_ms": "1584703627000",  
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2020-03-20 05:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "is_trial_period": "false",  
    "item_id": "15xxx27",  
    "unique_identifier": "cd5xxx424",  
    "original_transaction_id": "100xxx735",  
    "subscription_group_identifier": "20xxx02",  
    "transaction_id": "100xxx439",  
    "bid": "app.xxx",  
    "web_order_line_item_id": "100xxx419",  
    "purchase_date": "2020-03-20 11:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
    "product_id": "app.xxx",  
    "expires_date": "1584707227000",  
    "original_purchase_date": "2020-03-18 08:11:45 Etc/GMT",  
    "purchase_date_pst": "2020-03-20 04:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "original_purchase_date_ms": "1584519105000"  
  },  
  "latest_receipt": "xxx"  
}
```

I especially want to point out the following fields of that response:

```
{  
    ...  
  "latest_receipt_info": {  
      ...  
    "expires_date": "1584707227000",  
    "expires_date_formatted": "2020-03-20 12:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2020-03-20 05:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "subscription_group_identifier": "20xxx02",  
    "bid": "app.xxx",  
      ...  
  },  
  "receipt": {  
      ...  
    "expires_date": "1584707227636",  
    "expires_date_formatted": "2020-03-20 12:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
    "expires_date_formatted_pst": "2020-03-20 05:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "subscription_group_identifier": "20xxx02",  
    "bid": "app.xxx",  
      ...  
  },  
    ...  
}
```

The inconsistencies with the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt) are:

1. `latest_receipt_info` is [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody) to be an array, however, it is a single json object.
2. In the `latest_receipt_info`, the `expires_date` is not in "date-time format similar to the ISO 8601" as the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/latest_receipt_info) says, but looks like it is in milliseconds since epoch (what should be the `expires_date_ms`). However, we can find the key `expires_date_formatted` that is in date-time format.
3. The same fields as in (2) can be also found in the receipt, however, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/receipt) states only a key `expiration_date` (analogue to the `expires_date` in the `latest_receipt_info` in date-time format) and `expiration_date_ms` (in milliseconds since epoch).
4. The documented `bundle_id` key ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/latest_receipt_info) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/receipt)) is not present, but a key `bid` is, that contains the bundle id.
5. The key `subscription_group_identifer` does not contain the exact string entered in AppStoreConnect as subscription group identifer, as documented ([here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/latest_receipt_info) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/responsebody/receipt)), but contains some integer value.

So according to the documentation, the response should look like this, for me:

```
{  
    ...  
  "latest_receipt_info": [  
    {  
        ...  
      "expires_date": "2020-03-20 12:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
      "expires_date_ms": "1584707227000",  
      "expires_date_pst": "2020-03-20 05:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
      "subscription_group_identifier": "MY_SUBSCRIPTION_GROUP_ID",  
      "bundle_id": "app.xxx",  
        ...  
    }  
  ],  
  "receipt": {  
      ...  
    "expiration_date": "2020-03-20 12:27:07 Etc/GMT",  
    "expiration_date_ms": "1584707227636",  
    "expiration_date_pst": "2020-03-20 05:27:07 America/Los_Angeles",  
    "subscription_group_identifier": "MY_SUBSCRIPTION_GROUP_ID",  
    "bundle_id": "app.xxx",  
      ...  
  },  
    ...  
}
```

- I am not sure how to cope with that situation, is that a bug in the API or is the documentation simply wrong?
- Can I expect the same inconsistencies for the production endpoint (can someone share a sample response please)?
- How about the notifications in [server-to-server notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications), are there also inconsistencies?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone that faces the same problem: We sent the wrong receipt data to our backend since we requested the receipt via the deprecated [transactionReceipt](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransaction/1617722-transactionreceipt) and not via [appStoreReceiptURL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/bundle/1407276-appstorereceipturl).

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get that receipt example? Here is a proper receipt example from verifyReceipt endoint: https://gist.github.com/ren6/3da2d14ea629ab9add489c0e6df1917c

Also I can recommend you reading article from our blog: https://blog.apphud.com/receipt-validation/

Regarding Apple server-to-server notifications, they are now unified, i.e. data is being returned in the same structure as from `verifyReceipt` endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the example! Indeed, it is completely different to the response I got. However, I got the response after sending a request myself to the sandbox verifyReceipt endpoint with a Base64 encoded receipt. The receipt was sent to my server after making a purchase in a Nativescript Frontend using the latest version of the [Nativescript Purchase Plugin](https://npm.proplugins.org/-/web/detail/@proplugins/nativescript-purchase). The observed behaviour is consistent over several days and several attempts with different sandbox purchases.